# some variables doesn' t work on vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I wrote a function:

```
getClassTable () {
  var classNormalData = this.classData.normal,
      alterClasses = this.classData.alter.classes,
      classTable = [];

  for(var day in classNormalData) {
    classTable.push(classNormalData[day]);
  }

  if(alterClasses != []) {
    alterClasses.forEach(function(item, index) {
      var date = item.time,
          lesson = item.lesson;
      for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        var time = this.dates[i],
            classes = classTable[i][lesson];
        if(time == date) {
          classes.subject = item.subject;
          break;
        }
      }
    }, this)
  }
  this.classTable = classTable;
}
```

}

but when the `classes.subject = item.subject` works, somethings went wrong. It seemed change`this.classData`directly. The variables `classNormalData` `classTable` didn' t work well.
Why?

Ps: `this.classData` is defined here

```
computed: {
  classData () {
    return this.$localStorage.get('classList');
  },
}
```

Comment: Can you also add which ones are your vue variable, possible to reproduce in jsfiddle, any specific error you are getting in console?

Comment: Thank you. I have known how to solve it just now. It is because that when I set a obj as a variable, it actually links to the original object. I find a approach is to apply `var newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, variables as pointers to objects. When you assigning to a variable, you are not modifying any objects, merely repointing your variable to a different object. so if you modify the assigned object, original as well will change.

To overcome this, you have to create a new object which is clone of original object.
There are multiple way to do this, one way as you have pointed out in comment:

```
var newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

There are better and efficient ways to do this, like using [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
var newObj = Object.assign({}, obj)
```

[underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#clone) and [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#cloneDeep) also provides their clone methods.

You can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) for other solutions.